# I want to create a signup form to register a user by verifying weather the user is existed or not in the sqlite3 database

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to create a signup form to register a user by verifying weather the user is existed or not in the sqlite3 database.

here is my root urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('orphanageoperations.urls')),
]
```

sub url file:

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns=[
        path('',views.orphanage_main_page,name='orphanage_main_page'),
        path('signup.html',views.signup,name='signup'),
        path('login.html',views.login,name='login')
        ]
```

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SignupForm
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
    else:
        form=SignupForm()

    return render(request,'orphanageoperations/signup.html',{})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

class Signup(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=20);
    usermail=models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True);
    userph=models.CharField(max_length=13);
    userpwd=models.CharField(max_length=20);

    def createUser(self):
        self.username;
        self.usermail;
        self.userph;
        self.userpwd;
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Signup

class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Signup;
        fields=('username','usermail','userph','userpwd',);
```

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Signup</title>
    <meta charset="uts-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function validate_signup_form(){
            var username=document.getElementById("name").value;
            var mobilenum=document.getElementById("phno").value;
            var mailid=document.getElementById("userMail").value;
            var password=document.getElementById("pwd").value;
            if(username==""){
            alert("Please Enter the username");
            return false;
            }
            if(mobilenum==""){
            alert("Please Enter mobile number");
            return false;
            }
            if(mailid==""){
            alert("Plese enter your mail id");
            return false;
            }
            if(password==""){
            alert("Plese enter your password");
            return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <h4 style="padding-left:5em">Signup Form</h4>
        <form name="signupForm" action="signup" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return validate_signup_form()" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="phno">Mobile:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phno" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" name="phno">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="userMail" placeholder="Enter your mail" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:25px">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup
Using the URLconf defined in heretohelp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='orphanage_main_page']
signup.html [name='signup']
login.html [name='login']
The current path, signup, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Requesting all to help me on this case, i can't able to find where the error exists or what i did wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your html form action points to `/signup` url but I see no `/signup` url declared in urlpatterns. Try with `action=/signup.html`and if that works then better try to use named url patterns in template. `action={% ulr 'signup' %}`

Comment: Why are you adding signup.html in the url pattern when you have it in your views? Next thing is why another signup model? If you are using the Django User model, then the signup model will be of no use,and it will not check if the user exists in the database or not.

Comment: Thanks Bidhan Majhi, I tried your approach but not got the resolution. I started learning python web development recently so facing some issues.

Comment: If you want to write your own custom user try this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Sure, i will go through it. Thanks Raja Simon.